# React JS changing words in spherical word cloud

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, word-cloud

https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-demo-forked-yup2o?file=/src/App.js

I have the above sandbox of a spherical word cloud consisting of random words - I'm trying to modify the code so rather than random words, the cloud can display words from a list of my choosing, for example

`let MyList = ['React', 'Node', 'SQL', 'NoSQL', 'TDD', 'JavaScript', 'Python', 'Git', 'Excel', 'ReactNative', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'TypeScript', 'Java', 'Angular', 'Django']`

I tried doing this by editing the code inside the for loop of the cloud function by changing `randomWord()` to `wordFromMyList()` which is defined below.

```
function wordFromMyList() { 
    let y = MyList[0];
    MyList.shift();
    return y 
}
```

However this isn't working and doesn't return a spherical cloud at all - but if I instead change the `wordFromMyList()` function to just return 'hi' I get a spherical word cloud with only the word 'hi' which is confusing me as to why the shift function doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to too many re-renders (4 to be exact) and by then your `MyList` is already shifted more than 16 times and is empty. So your function `wordFromMyList` is always returning `undefined` by the 4rth render and nothing is getting displayed.

Use `i` and `j` variables in the two loops to get the word from your list like this

```
  function wordFromMyList(i, j) {
    return MyList[i * 4 + j];
  }
```